# Excel If/And Statement, Multiple

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I need a formula that will display "10" in a cell if another cell is between 10.00-12.49. If it is between 12.50-19.99, I need it to display 12.50. Finally, if it is over 20.00, I need it to display 20.00.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just require a simple LOOKUP formula.

```
=lookup(a1, {0, 10, 12.5, 20}, {"under", 10, 12.5, 20})
```

Comment: This works great! What is the best way to tie an error in? The minimum limit is 10, but say a cell has a value of 9, I would want to return "Under".

Answer (score 1):

Suppose Cell A1 contains the value you are inspecting.

This formula should do what you described:

```
=IFERROR(CHOOSE(MATCH(A1,{10,12.5,20},1),10,12.5,20),"Less than 10")
```

I made a couple of assumptions.

1. I assumed that when you gave a range you were including both the starting and end point of the range where specified.
2. I assumed that you wanted something intercepting the error that would result if the value in A1 was less than the lowest value in the items you noted.

Comment: I think this is really close. In one example, C10=10.00 but the formula returned 12.50.

Comment: Can you post your exact formula, please.  I cannot get it to do this, assuming that instead of A1 you are pointing the formula to C10.  It should not matter where the cell under scrutiny is.  It would happen if you added a zero to the first set and did not add a zero to the second set.  One of the reasons why I chose this formula is because it translates easily to a set of values in a range of cells.  If you used it that way, it would be easier to update and easier to see a missing value.

Comment: =LOOKUP(C10, {0,10,12.5,20}, {"",10,12.5,20}) In this case, C10= 12.49 and D10 (where the formula lives) is returning 10.

Comment: That is the somewhat more elegant solution that Jeeped offered (i.e., not mine), but it should not matter. What you are seeing is the difference between the phrase between and from/to.  Both Jeeped and I assumed that the range included both the starting and ending numbers (i.e., 10 and 12.49).  Everything starting at 10 will show 10 until the value is at least 12.5 for both of our formulas.  If you want 12.49 to show 12.5, the ranges would need to change.

Comment: I was off somewhere. It works. I appreciate all the help.